# Evitar llamado al web service para depurar aplicacion asp.net con datos de ejemplo

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice, aplicación-web, depuración

Tengo una aplicacion Asp.Net en VisualStudio 2013 y SQL Server 2014 y necesito depurarla sin que llame al web service y me devuelva a modo de prueba un numero de factura cualquiera y que me diga que dicha factura está paga.
Aca tengo habilitada la depuración:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Aca tengo el web service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ServiceSoap" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="ServiceSoap1" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client> 
  <endpoint address="https:MiWebService.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap" contract="ContractWebService" name="ServiceSoap" />
</client>
```

Lo que pensaba era setear alguna variable que me habilite o desabilite el web service y pueda hardcodear los datos que necesito (que me devuelva un numero de factura y otro dato que me diga que está paga por ejemplo)

Comment: Buenas, en estos casos que necesitas realizar pruebas lo que haría sería crear una interfaz para ese servicio. La clase del servicio heredaría de esta interfaz por lo que tu podrías pasarlo como parametro e implentar otra clase que sería donde meterías la función que devuelve datos falsos.

Comment: A ver si entiendo (No manejo muy bien el tema de las interfaces). Creo la interfaz IWebServiceTest (esto sería para "simular" el ws?) y hago que WebServeiceTest herede de IWebServiceTest. Lo que no entiendo es esto: _podrías pasarlo como parametro e implentar otra clase que sería donde meterías la función que devuelve datos falsos_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te lo pongo por aqui:

```
interface IWebService
{
    string devuelveFactura();
    bool estaPagada();
}
```

Ahora a tu servicio haces que herede de este:

```
class WebService: IWebService{
    string devuelveFactura() {....} 
}
```

Te creas una clase para simular el web service falso Web service Falso

```
class WebServiceFalso: IWebService{
    string devuelveFactura() {....} 
}
```

Donde vayas a usar el webservice pues simplemente haces esto

```
   IWebService webFalso = new WebServiceFalso();
```

Ahora donde vas a usar este webservice? Se lo pasas por parametro o lo llamas directamente?

En el caso que se lo pases por parametro a alguna función sería:

```
public void obtenerFactura(IWebService webService){ .....}
```

Puedes observar que la función recibe como parametro una interface por lo que no sabe si el objeto es de la clase WebService o WebServiceFalse, y solo tienes que llamar a los metodos que se definio en la interface.

Espero que te valga la explicación